# Ubuntu slow launching with SSD 36 seconds

Tags: 18.04, ssd, performance

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday and after some hard first steps really enjoying this platform. I have only one system installed on my whole PC and it is Ubuntu. I am running SSD drive. Here is my screen from GParted. [GPart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q77X.png)

I have other 1 TB HDD drive but all space there is unallocated.
systemd-analize blame

```
20.332s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         15.955s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          1.083s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
           864ms snap-chromium\x2dffmpeg-13.mount
           844ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
           834ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           799ms fwupd.service
           787ms snap-spotify-35.mount
           782ms systemd-resolved.service
           768ms snap-opera-38.mount
           756ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount
           750ms systemd-logind.service
           738ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
           733ms snap-core-6350.mount
           732ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
           717ms snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-203.mount
           707ms snap-wine\x2dplatform-128.mount
           700ms snap-core18-970.mount
           633ms snap-firefox-216.mount
           626ms snap-communitheme-1768.mount
           459ms keyboard-setup.service
           441ms NetworkManager.service
           411ms motd-news.service
```

Cheers,

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `systemd-analyze blame`, or at least the first 10-20 lines.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have added it, If I can format it just please tell me how to do it :)

Comment: I turned off playmouth and NetworkManager but time is still the same. Now when I am booting I can see some many code that is being executed while launching Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, after about 15 seoncds I can see kind of ubuntu wallpaper color while booting, it dissapears, some logging messages are showing on black screens and finally I have my system ready to go.

Comment: Here is how my booting screen looks like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdjAn-nLek0